# When can such errors on bind() happen?

Tags: c, linux, bind

Errors taken from `man bind`

```
    ENOTSOCK // sockfd is a descriptor for a file, not a socket. The following errors are specific to UNIX domain (AF_UNIX) sockets:
    EFAULT // addr points outside the user's accessible address space.
    ELOOP // Too many symbolic links were encountered in resolving addr.
    ENOENT // The file does not exist.
    ENOTDIR // A component of the path prefix is not a directory.
    EROFS// The socket inode would reside on a read-only file system.
```

Especially i can't understand when ELOOP, ENOENT, ENOTDIR, EROFS can happen. Is this is related for some special filesystems like nfs and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that sockets and `bind` can be used for more than network communication. See for example [Unix domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) which are bound as files in a file system.

It's even there in your own quoted list of errors:

> The following errors are specific to UNIX domain (AF_UNIX) sockets

Comment: So, i shouldn't care about them in error handling when using them for network communication only?

Comment: @Maquefel No, but you should at least be aware that there are other errors besides the ones you want to handle, and at least print something useful when they occur (`perror`/`strerror` are nice for this).